# Unity(dependency injection container) hook right object based on the validation object

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I need to replace following line:

```
var validator = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IValidator<T>>();
```

in

```
public class ValidationFactory : IValidationFactory
{
    public void Validate<T>(T entity) where T : class, IEntity
    {
        var validator = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IValidator<T>>();

        var result = validator.Validate(entity);

        if (result.Count() > 0)
            throw new BusinessServicesException(result);
    }
}
```

I need to referance: System.Web.Mvc
to be able to make it work.

Is there any other solution to hook right validator using unity?

Interfaces

```
public interface IValidator<T> where T : class, IEntity
{
    IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(T entity);
}

public interface IValidationFactory
{
    void Validate<T>(T entity) where T : class, IEntity;
}
```

One particullar validator:

```
public class CanCreateOrUpdateUserValidator : IValidator<User>
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public CanCreateOrUpdateUserValidator(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(User entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("");
        }
        else
        {
            // more logic                
        }
    }
}
```

Unity registration:

```
container.RegisterType<IValidationFactory, ValidationFactory>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IValidator<User>, CanCreateOrUpdateUserValidator>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do two things:

1. Inject the unity container into the `ValidationFactory` constructor. However, since Unity shouldn't be referenced from any lower layers, this means that the `ValidationFactory` implementation should be moved into the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). Considering the small amount of code inside this class, this shouldn't be a problem.
2. Instead of injecting the Unity container, inject a `Func<Type, object>` delegate that allows creating `IValidator<T>` implementations for you. When you register the `IValidationFactory` you supply a single `ValidationFactory` instance that you `new` up on the spot using this delegate:

```cs
container.RegisterInstance<IValidationFactory>(
    new ValidationFactory(type => container.Resolve(type)));
```

Unity does not contain any batch registration facilities out-of-the-box, so you have to hand-write this batch registration of your validators. Unity does however allow you to map open generic interfaces to open generic implementations, like this:

```
container.RegisterType(
    typeof(IValidator<>),
    typeof(NullValidator<>));
```

This allows you to always return a validator and it saves the validation factory from ever having to check whether a validator exists for a given `T`.

Comment: Would factory pattern be more "appropriate" to solve the problem? In that case I dont need DI container.

Comment: @Dzenan: If this is the only place you 'need' a DI container, that might be because [it tries to solve a problem you might not have but it's a nice problem to have](http://kozmic.net/2012/10/23/ioc-container-solves-a-problem-you-might-not-have-but-its-a-nice-problem-to-have/).

Comment: @Dzenan: I don't understand. The `ValidationFactory` _is_ a factory so you're already using a factory.

Comment: I was confused. You make a good point in the first comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service locator using `Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation`

```
    //on init app
    Dim container As IUnityContainer = New UnityContainer()
    container.RegisterType<IValidationFactory, ValidationFactory>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IValidator<User>, CanCreateOrUpdateUserValidator>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    Dim provider = New UnityServiceLocator(container)
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(Function() provider)
```

And in your ValidatorFactory:

```
var validator = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IValidator<T>>();//returns configured class
```

But this creates a dependency for `Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation` and I always think servicelocator is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Hi jvaquero, Yes indeed I need to remove dependency.